# Why does my AES decryption return extra bytes?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Regardless of the file size, 32 bytes of additional characters are appended to each decrypted file. I could just cut off the 32 bytes, but where did they come from and how can I avoid them in the output file?

This is my source code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

public class EtAesCrypto {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int IV_LENGTH = 12;
    private static final int AUT_TAG_LENGTH = 128;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 100;

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";

    private String msg;

    public void encrypt(String path2Original, String path2Encrypted, String password) {
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path2Encrypted)) {
            byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
            byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];

            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);

            secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            logger.trace("IV length: {}", iv.length);

            out.write(salt);
            out.write(iv);

            Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AUT_TAG_LENGTH, iv);
            ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, parameterSpec);

            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path2Original)) {
                processStream(ci, in, out);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encryption of file with id failed.");
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(String path2Encrypted, OutputStream os, String password, String fileId) {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path2Encrypted)) {
            doDecryption(in, os, password);
        } catch (Exception e){
            msg = String.format("Decryption of file with id '%s' failed.", fileId);
            logger.warn("Decryption of file '{}' with id '{}' failed: {}", path2Encrypted, fileId, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(String path2Encrypted, String path2Decrypted, String password, String fileId) {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path2Encrypted)) {
            try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path2Decrypted)) {
                doDecryption(in, os, password);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            msg = String.format("Decryption of file with id '%s' failed.", fileId);
            logger.warn("Decryption of file '{}' with id '{}' failed: {}", path2Encrypted, fileId, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
    }

    private void doDecryption(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];

        int saltBytes = in.read(salt);
        int ivBytes = in.read(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);

        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(AUT_TAG_LENGTH, iv);
        ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, parameterSpec);

        processStream(ci, in, out);
    }

    private void processStream(Cipher ci, InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
        byte[] inBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(inBuffer)) != -1) {
            byte[] outBuffer = ci.update(inBuffer, 0, len);
            if (outBuffer != null)
                out.write(outBuffer);
        }
        byte[] outBuffer = ci.doFinal();
        if (outBuffer != null)
            out.write(outBuffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` when decrypting.

The additional bytes are the GCM tag (MAC). It is created during encryption and checked during decryption.

In GCM mode the process of encryption and decryption is identical (XOR), that's why decrypting with `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` appears to work, except for the MAC part.